# Keep rows which are not unique but have different labels in another column in R

Tags: r, subset, unique

I have a data frame called 'dataframe'

It has a column of 'exposures' e.g. ABC, DEF, GHI and a column of 'labels' red and yellow. They can be on one row labelled 'red' or on multiple rows labelled 'red' or also on multiple rows both 'yellow' and 'red'

```
Exposure   Label
ABC        yellow
DEF        yellow
GHI        red
GHI        red
GHI        red
JKL        yellow
DEF        red
ABC        yellow
ABC        red
```

How do I extract those which are in their multiple times but with different colours? So here I would want to keep ABC because it's both yellow and red but lose GHI because they're only red.

So far I've only been able to keep those which are non-unique

```
both <- dataframe %>% group_by(Exposure) %>% filter(n()>1)
```

But can't figure out how to specify to keep those which ONLY have different labels, not the same labels?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(data.table)
# Sample data
DT <- fread("Exposure   Label
ABC        yellow
DEF        yellow
GHI        red
GHI        red
GHI        red
JKL        yellow
DEF        red
ABC        yellow
ABC        red")

# Filter based more than 1 unique Label by Exposure-group
DT[, if(uniqueN(Label) > 1) .SD, by = Exposure]

#    Exposure  Label
# 1:      ABC yellow
# 2:      ABC yellow
# 3:      ABC    red
# 4:      DEF yellow
# 5:      DEF    red
```

Comment: Or we can do `setDT(dataframe)[, .SD[uniqueN(Label) > 1], Exposure]`

Answer (score 2):

`n()` would give number of rows in group, `n_distinct(Label)` would give count of unique values.

```
library(dplyr)
dataframe %>% group_by(Exposure) %>% filter(n_distinct(Label)>1) %>% ungroup

#  Exposure Label 
#  <chr>    <chr> 
#1 ABC      yellow
#2 DEF      yellow
#3 DEF      red   
#4 ABC      yellow
#5 ABC      red
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a new column merged of the two columns and then subset using unique.

```
df$x <- paste(df$Exposure,df$Label)

df <- df[!duplicated(df$x), ]
```

All the very best,
Kurt

Answer (score 1):

A base R option

```
subset(
  dataframe,
  ave(Label, Exposure, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) > 1
)
```

gives

```
  Exposure  Label
1      ABC yellow
2      DEF yellow
7      DEF    red
8      ABC yellow
9      ABC    red
```